# Combining scores for a given factor level in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in **R** that is 3 columns and many rows, laid out like this:

```
Zip      Yes/No   Likelihood-of-Yes/No
75229    1        0.83
75229    0        0.4
28277    1        0.6
```

where there are many entries for each zip code. I would like to reshape this data frame into a table that gives the average score for each zip code, but I'm not sure how. I've considered `apply`ing a `mean` to each zip after making `Zip` a factor, but I don't know if that's the right way to go about it.

Comment: How does you desired output should look like for the data set provided?

Comment: I would like one entry per zipcode (as an example, 75229), with the Yes/No column for all 75229 entries added together, and the Likelihood entry equal to the mean of all Likelihood entries corresponding to zip 75229

Comment: I dont quite understand your data (sorry) - why do you have two `Likelihood-of-Yes/No` for the same `Zip` (75229). Anyway, could `?aggregate` be of help here?

Comment: How the 'Yes/No' column should be treated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a data.frame as an output, I find `aggregate` the best way to go:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"Zip      YesNo   LikelihoodYesNo
75229    1        0.83
75229    0        0.4
28277    1        0.6")

datnew <- aggregate(YesNo ~ Zip, data=dat, sum)
datnew$LikelihoodYesNo <- aggregate(LikelihoodYesNo ~ Zip, data=dat, mean)[,2]
```

In the code above I renamed you variables. It's usually a good idea to avoid characters lile `/` in variable names.

Result:

```
> datnew
    Zip YesNo LikelihoodYesNo
1 28277     1           0.600
2 75229     1           0.615
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df = read.table(text = "Zip      Yes/No   Likelihood-of-Yes/No
75229    1        0.83
75229    0        0.4
28277    1        0.6", header = T)

by(df, df$Zip, function(x) mean(x$Lik))

df$Zip: 28277
[1] 0.6
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$Zip: 75229
[1] 0.615
```

Comment: A wee bit more compactly `by(df$Lik, df$Zip, mean)`